# Convert Object to double Scriptengine

Tags: java, object, double, valueconverter, scriptengine

Im using the java scriptengine to evaluate the math of a string i have.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class GraphYPosAlg 
{
  public static double YPos(String funktion) {
    Double tempDouble;
    ScriptEngineManager StringToInt = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = StringToInt.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    tempDouble = engine.eval(funktion);
    return tempDouble;
  }
}
```

I get the error "required: java.lang.Double, found: java.lang.Object" I need to convert the engine.eval(funktion); into a double but how?!?!?!?

Please describe much im pretty new to programming.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could invoke the `toString()` method on the object and create a `double` out of it:

```
tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(engine.eval(funktion).toString());
```